# How to remove features from grub2

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I am looking for a way to remove the features that allow command line and live edit on grub options.

I am setting up policies to make sure that workers at a company are unable to change the base system of a machine. The first step was to lock the boot sequence and require a password in order to boot from a removable device, but one can still boot from a removable device using the grub command line mode or editing the options.

Is there a way to remove these features? And how?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Have you tried following [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Security) where it says "empty string effectively disables both access to CLI and editing of menu entries"? Where are you stuck?

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/JohnstonJ/ubuntu-secure-boot) also locks down GRUB, you may want to look at its sources.